# Android AdMob clicking but not opening website

Tags: android

My Android app has AdMob. Ads are showing, but when I click an ad the app closes but the ad website is not opening. This is my code:

My View:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
  android:id="@+id/adViewm"
  ads:adSize="BANNER"
  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-*****/****"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

My Activity:

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adViewm);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

My Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
```

My Manifest:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" >
</activity>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2gbc.png)

Comment: Adding `play-services` and `play-services-ads` is redundant as adding `play-services` adds everything.  You should simply add `play-services-ads` and let it pull in `core` intrinsically.  Note, however, that this is not why your app is not working, but rather a call out to bad dependencies.  And the formatting of this question is terrible ;)

Comment: English is not my main language, i am very bad to speak english.. for the reason, i dont understand your comment exactly.. thanks for your help..

Comment: Remove `play-services` dependency.  It is not required by this code.

Comment: Also, your app must be crashing.  Include output from LogCat please.

Comment: i am using play services for notification..

Comment: is is very interesting, when i use app on my phone, ads is showing normally, but when using emulator, ads showing like test ads..

Comment: and when app is crashing, not say app is stopped, i think not crashing, maybe ads is not really ads maybe test, but i not using test

Comment: Emulators always generate test ads.  That is by design.

Comment: You are using Play Services for "notification."  Push Notifications?  If so, change `play-services` to `play-services-gcm` and remove `play-services`.